Provide default value for a missing JSON property when deserializing
I have sample JSON like this:
                        {
                            "Type": "Service",
                            "Uid": "Bridge 1",
                            "ServiceName": "Bridge 1"
                        }

Which I deserialize to a class like:
public record ServiceConfig
{
    public required string Type { get; init; }
    public required string Uid { get; init; }
    public required string ServiceName { get; init; }
}

var cfg = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ServiceConfig>(stream);
I would like ServiceName to be optional in the JSON and when it is not provided, the Uid value is used instead, so that the following two JSONs lead to the same result:
                        {
                            "Type": "Service",
                            "Uid": "Bridge 1",
                            "ServiceName": "Bridge 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "Type": "Service",
                            "Uid": "Bridge 1"
                        },

Is there a simple way to do this, without having to manually parse the JSON DOM instead of using automated deserialization?

You could implement some logic in the ServiceName property
public record ServiceConfig
{
    public required string Type { get; init; }
    public required string Uid { get; init; }

    private string? _serviceName;
    public string ServiceName {
        get => _serviceName ?? Uid; // Returns Uid is _serviceName is null.
        init => _serviceName = value;
    }
}

I removed the required modifier since is seems to not make sense when ServiceName is optional.

Based on the usecase you can leverage the ctor handling by System.Text.Json:
public record ServiceConfig
{
    [JsonConstructor] // not actually required since it is a single ctor
    public ServiceConfig(string type, string uid, string? serviceName)
    {
        Type = type;
        Uid = uid;
        ServiceName = serviceName ?? uid;
    }

    public string Type { get; }
    public string Uid { get; }
    public string ServiceName { get; } 
}

See Use immutable types and properties: Parameterized constructors section of the docs.

If you don't want (or can't) change the record definition, you can create a custom converter (the following is very naive and must be improved!):
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json;

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new CustomConverter());

var test = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ServiceConfig>("{\"Type\": \"Service\", \"Uid\": \"Bridge 1\", \"ServiceName\": \"Service Name 1\"}", options);

// test.ServiceName => Service Name 1

var test2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ServiceConfig>("{\"Type\": \"Service\", \"Uid\": \"Bridge 1\"}", options);

// test.ServiceName => Bridge 1

public record ServiceConfig
{
    public required string Type { get; init; }
    public required string Uid { get; init; }
    public required string ServiceName { get; init; }
}

public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter<ServiceConfig>
{
    public override ServiceConfig Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        string? type = null, uid = null, serviceName = null;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                var prop = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();
                var value = reader.GetString();

                switch (prop)
                {
                    case "Type":
                        type = value;
                        break;
                    case "Uid":
                        uid = value;
                        break;
                    case "ServiceName":
                        serviceName = value;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (type is null || uid is null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Bad JSON");
        }

        return new ServiceConfig
        {
            Type = type,
            Uid = uid,
            ServiceName = serviceName ?? uid
        };
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ServiceConfig value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

